# Finding String on C++

Tags: c++, search

I got a task from my teacher. I try some code but it confuses me a lot. So here's my code :

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

char inputChecker [1000];
string source = "10110111000111001101110";
string detected;

int main(){
    cout <<"Input:";
    cin >> inputChecker;
    for (int i=0;i<source.size();i++){
        if (source[i]==inputChecker[0]){
            cout <<"Data " <<inputChecker <<"is exist" <<endl; 
        }
        else if (source[i]==inputChecker[i]){
            cout <<"Data " <<inputChecker <<" isn't exist'" <<endl;
        }
    }
}
```

So ,my expectation output is ,when i input 10,it will result "Data 10 is exist". Without looping. I think it needed 2 kind of looping but i dont know where to loop.

My expectation output :

```
Input : 10
Data 10 is exist

Input : 25
Data 25 isn't exist
```

Thanks in advance :))

Comment: Why not use `find` that `std::string` provides?

Comment: There is no reason to make your variables global.

Comment: Aside - using namespace std is generally [considered bad](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

Comment: what kind of find sir? i try it but its error -_- @NathanOliver

Comment: [this one](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for loop

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string source = "10110111000111001101110";
    string input;
    cin >> input;
    if (source.find(input) != string::npos)
        cout << input << " exists\n";
    else
        cout << input <<" doesn't exist\n";
}
```

Have a look at other useful [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) methods like [`find_first_of`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find_first_of), [`find_last_of`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find_last_of), etc.

Comment: I never knew that .find is exists in c++ :(( anyway , it helps me a lot sir. Thanks !